# What software are there to use on laptop for blood analysis and diagnosis?

Tags: blood-tests, medical-device, diagnosis

I wanted to know if there are any softwares that by installing on a notebook can allow me to do initial diagnosis of a patient at ordinary locations. Does anybody know what softwares are there or maybe even some portable or mountable hardware for quick blood test? thank you!

Comment: If this isn't life and death machinery you need ebay sometimes has everything from EEG machines to more obscure items.  I myself would not know what this are called.

Comment: Do you mean equipment that can literally analyze a blood sample or do you mean software that can interpret results from a laboratory?

Comment: There are different kinds of point of care testing but the question is what specifically do you want to test for, and do you know how to interpret and apply the results?

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is usually considered off topic for most stack exchange sites

Answer (score 2):

No there isn’t. Your computer is lacking the hardware diagnostic tools, so a software won’t be able to help.

An actual blood test is a compilation of multiple tests done by experts in a lab, and even the simplest and faster forms (an ABG, as an example takes <5 minutes) use machines which cost [more than 300 dollars for sure](https://www.labx.com/blood-gas-analyzers).

Where would you inject a blood sample into the computer to start with...?